# Clustering Medium length (100bp) DNA Sequences

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, bioinformatics, biopython, dna-sequence

Hello I am trying to cluster a pool of 70 DNA sequence fasta files that are around 100 bp's in length (GCAT) in order to compare genotype clusters with my phenotype clusters in order to validate phenotype results.

What do you think is the feasibility of a one hot encoding followed by a kmeans clustering algorithm in order to do this?

Some problems I've come across with current sequence clustering software (DBSCAN, ALFATCLUST) are that they seem to focus primarily on longer dna sequences, meaning that it would always throw all of the sequences into one group, or just the sequences out all together. Generally speaking, these algorithms are also very sensitive to noise (inherent to DNA seq), which often leads to inaccurate clusters.

Any ideas how I can figure out this problem?

I tried to cluster with DBSCAN, kmeans, cmeans, ALFATCLUST, etc. but am getting faulty clusters.

Comment: With 70 sequences you can just do a multiple sequence alignment and build a phylogenetic tree. Overlay your tree with the phenotype information to see if the tree is concordant with the observed phenotypes.

Comment: With your suggestion I did the MSA and built the tree using ClusterO and UGENE. Do you have any suggestions on how I would overlay my tree with the phenotype information? Should I try to build a phylogenetic/dendrogram with the phenotype data and then use a phylogenetic tree comparison software?

Sorry if these are basic questions; I'm and undergrad quite new to this field

Comment: The leaves on your tree are individual sequences. From your question I assumed you have a phenotype for each individual sequence. Simply check if the genotypic clustering (your tree) matches your phenotypic information.

Comment: each of my phenotypes is a GFP curve across time, which means I would need to cluster the GFP curves first

Comment: If i needed a form of statistical measure to see correlation, what statistical measure could i use?